# CSV import error in meteor

Tags: csv, meteor

In my meteor app I'm using Jquery csv plugin to import CSV files.This is the sample code.

```
var data =  $.csv.toArray(res);
```

it is working fine for certain csv files and I'm getting the data correctly.
But for some other, this is error is displayed in console.

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'saveFile': Error: CSVDataError: Illegal Quote [Row:1][Col:4]
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery-csv.js?ea39e3690e981dde83917bbac36c9cbd909d649f:33:4117
```

All the files are of the same format and so is it the problem of the code or the csv file ?

Now I found like the problem occurs if there is double quotes like `coloumns1,Something "example",coloumn3`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the parser is very strict in what it expects as a delimiter and a quote.

According to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/issues/detail?id=21) and [this one](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/issues/detail?id=22) there should be no space before or after the separating comma, therefore

this is illegal:

```
"val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"
```

while this is legal:

```
"val1","val2","val3","val4"
```

Also, depending on the contents of your *cells* and your surrounding parser's code, you may need to escape either one of (not both) single or double quotes as in either `\'` or `\"`

Comment: changed like this coloumns1,Something \"example\",coloumn3... Still not working.

Comment: @NidhinzzOwn take a look at the updated answer, it seems this is something different and the error message is misleading

Comment: Author of jquery-csv here. The parser follows the spec which says to to escape a quote with another quote. Whitespace, as in the space before and after values is ignored by the parser so that shouldn't cause any issues.